# pass scope variable from directive to a controller function

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have a scope function which I am calling from the directive, in that scope function I am passing a sciopoe variable. The scope variable is getting changed in that function.

```
    <button ng-click="change(scope_variable)"></button>
```

controller

```
    $scope.change = function(var){
         //some manipulations with var
    }
```

In this case the scope variable is not getting changed, only var is getting changed. What can I do to change the scope variable itself.

Edit:

The scope variable that I am passing is an array and the changes I am making is mostly sorting, insertion and deletion of values from the array.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the change you're trying to make ? Since you can't change the reference, you might be able to do other stuff.

Comment: directives are isolated so you wont be able to change the variable directly. You could use a shared service to update the variable and have that available to the controller.

Answer (score 0):

1. the `scope` has a reference to var, but var no reference to scope. if you assign a new value to var `scope` will keep the reference to the old var and not update. if `var` is an object or an array you can modify it and see the changes in the `scope`.
2. Don't name variables `var`. `var` is a reserved keyword and might be misleading.

Comment: var is an array only but scope variable is not getting updated.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to pass a scope variable from the view. You can access the scope variable from your controller.

```
//In the view
    <button ng-click="change('somevalue')"></button>

//In your controller
    $scope.change = function(someVal){
             $scope.someVar = someVal;
             //some manipulations with someVar  
    }
```

Comment: Yes, but I want to pass different scope variables to the function and final value of scope variables should change.

Comment: I would suggest you pass some value to the function and interpret that or set that value to the scope variable.

Comment: Yeah but that would require a lot of if-else statements. I am trying to escape that. Is there no other way in angular?

Answer (score 0):

And how about doing this way:

```
//In the view
<button ng-click="change()"></button>

//In your controller
$scope.someArray = [1, 2, 3];

$scope.change = function(){
    $scope.someArray.push(4);
}
```

Comment: I have several arrays that can be modified.